# What is the Tibetan prayer recited by the Dali Lama at the beginning of his 1989 Nobel Prize acceptance speech?

Tags: tibetan-buddhism, translation

At 2:48 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtkMZMkI5N8&t=168s) of the acceptance speech, a Tibetan prayer is recited. What is its translation into English?

I think it's something like "Gautama, the true Buddha... free from all precept". I once saw a translation in a YouTube comment but have lost it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the prayer translates in English as follows:

> “I bow to him, Gautama, who, by means of compassion, taught the true
> dharma for the purpose of abandoning all views” (Mūlamadhyamakakārikā
> 27.30).